# Fullpage js : section image with fixed position

Tags: css, fullpage.js

I am having totally 6 section, i have add one image inside the 2nd section and it should not go away when scrolling, the image should stay from 2nd section to 6th section.

Answer (score 0):

That's a basic CSS related question.
Use a fixed position for it:

HTML

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

CSS

```
#image{
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but the problem is, i added this image inside the section 2, but when the user scrolls the image is going away with the section. what i want is i want to add an image inside the section 2 not in first section, first section filled with something else, second section that image should appear up to last section.